# How do I print rows of a csv file that have a specific keyword in them

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to open two csv files, one with data (minidata.csv) and one with keywords (minikeys.csv), and search through the first one for keywords from the second one, and then print out the lines from the first one that include the keywords from the second one. Hope that makes sense.

I've tried opening the keywords file (minikeys.csv) as a list and searching from there, but I've come the closest to success by opening it into a dictionary for some reason.

```
with open('minidata.csv', 'r') as f:    
    text = f.read()
    csvFileArray = []

    with open('minikeys.csv', 'r') as inf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        mydict = {rows[0] for rows in reader}

    for key in mydict:
        for row in text:
            if key in text:            
                print(row)
```

This will get it to print out every line in the minidata.csv file, not the matching ones, but it also prints out each character as many times as there is a character in the minikeys. So it'll give me output like:

aaaa,,,,bbbb,,,,cccc,,,,dddd...

instead of printing out the lines that match.

What should I do instead to get this to work?

Comment: `mydict = {rows[0] for rows in reader}` should be `myset = {rows[0] for rows in reader}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
text = f.read()
```

do

```
text = f.readlines()
```

The issue here is that you're reading it as one big long string with the newlines included - whereas you want to be reading as a list of lines. In essence, `f.readlines()` is roughly equivalent to `f.read().split('\n')` (not entirely, but similar enough for this particular comparison). Hence, why you see the output you do - you're iterating *per character*, not *per line*.

Changing `text` so that it ends up as a list of strings rather than just one string should fix your issue.

---

Also, minor terminology thing. You said `mydict = {rows[0] for rows in reader}` is a `dict`. It's not - it's a `set`. `dict`s are specifically for key-value pairs, whereas `set`s are just keys. They're both implemented as hashtables.

Comment: That actually stopped giving me output at all. I printed out the set and the text at the end and it prints it out as one line: ['1,2,3,4\n', 'a,b,c,d\n', 'w,x,y,z']. when I leave it as read, its prints out 3 lines: 1,2,3,4 on the first, a,b,c,d on the second, etc. but the formatting is exactly like I just typed.